# Printing a graph function

Tags: java, graph

I need to create a void function named "PrintGraph"  that takes one integer parameter and prints(not returns) what a typical cartesian graph looks like and should work with any given size but for testing purposes we can assume it'll never be greater than 7. How would i start something like this?

Comment: Do you mean printing [ascii graph to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47166907/printing-a-graph-from-a-char-in-java) ?

Comment: I think you can "start something like this" by first creating a program that has a `printGraph` function that takes one integer. Even if all it does is print that integer to the console, you're on your way!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a graph of dashes, I would recommend taking the number, n, and printing (" " n times, then "|" ) n times, skipping a line in between, then printing "-" 2n times, then repeating the first procedure to create the negative y axis.

Example:

```
    //initialize the value for n below
    int n;
    for (int i=0;i<=n;i++){
       for (int a=0;a<=n;a++){
           System.out.print(" ");
       }
    System.out.println("|");
    }
    for (int b=o;b<=((2*n)+1);b++){
        System.out.print("-");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int c=0;c<=n;c++){
       for (int d=0;d<=n;d++){
           System.out.print(" ");
       }
    System.out.println("|");
    }
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This code does not compile. It is recommended to check  code before posting.

Comment: I changed the variables that overlapped in scope, but you have to initialize n with whatever integer you want for the size of the graph. It's also not perfect (a bit oblong) but is just a suggestion of a possible method.